# How to post exception on main thread while getting an exception in async task

Tags: android, multithreading, http, android-asynctask

I have an async task that goes to DB and fetches data. once in a while, the DB connection is lost and I'm getting an exception while I'm inside the async task and the application crushes.
My question is there a way to catch the connection lost exception while I'm in the async thread and publish a message to user that the connection was lost and prevent my application from crushing.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Alex

Comment: post your stack trace and relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Store the `Exception` in a data member of the `AsyncTask`, when you catch it in `doInBackground()`

Step #2: In `onPostExecute()`, if you have an `Exception` stored in that data member, do something with it (e.g., [display a crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {

    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
            {
                         try{
                                      //Access DB here
                                      return "Success";
                                    }
                                 catch(Exception e)
                                   { 
                                     return "Exception"
                                     }
            }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
        {

        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) 
                {
                    //Do your operation
                }
            else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception"))
                {
                    //Display Exception here
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: This assumes that `doInBackground()` does not have a more useful return value for non-`Exception` cases, and it loses the details of the `Exception` itself (e.g., for logging purposes, or for providing more specific information based on the type of `Exception`).

Comment: We sure can return non-Exception values from doInBackground(). Inside the try/catch block, we can call a function where we can return different values for non-Exceptional cases. Also, we can print the exception using e.printStackTrace() to know the nature of the Exception or use nested try/catch block to catch a specific kind of Exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to implement this ASAP. One more thing, if this async task can be called from several activities, how can I notify the user on the exception? Again thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not a problem, I thought CommonsWare's answer solved your issue. If you need to notify the user with the same message, you can call the AsyncTask class from different activities and display notification the same way I suppose.

Comment: Thansk. I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is partially worked. i.e. I was able to catch the exception, which is great, but the async task class is not part of my activity (not an internal class), not a helper class that doesn't extend activity. my question is how can i notify the user in such case? thank in advance.Alex